# Twitch Authentication with Java http request

Tags: java, httprequest

I'm new to Java http request. I'm trying to connect twitch chat with my Java code, however I need authentication to twitch. I registered my program to Twitch application and took client_id etc. How can I make Twitch Authorization Code Flow with Java http request ? I will appreciate any help and suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be old: but look up these two things: http://www.twitchapps.com/tmi/
And this: http://www.jibble.org/pircbot.php

Using both of these it is possible through IRC.

Comment: I followed same way, but I created my own IRC bot and forgot to post my solution. Anyway this is the right solution. Thanks.